# TypeError: string indices must be integers - Guardando datos de un JSON a la base de datos

Tags: django, json, django-models

Tengo la siguiente situación:

El modelo `RehabilitationSession` además de otros datos estos campos de interés:

```
class RehabilitationSession(models.Model):
             ...
    minimum = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5,decimal_places=2,verbose_name='Valor mínimo'
    )

    maximum = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2,verbose_name='Valor máximo'
    )

    median = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5,decimal_places=2,verbose_name='Valor medio'
    )

    mode = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2,verbose_name='Valor moda'
    )
                  ...
```

En este modelo, su información se completa con un archivo JSON que provee información de una aplicación externa y precisamente ese JSON me brinda los valores para estos campos de `minimum`, `median`, `mode` y `maximum`

Entonces es en el comportamiento de la vista de Detalle de un objeto `RehabilitationSession` en donde deseo tomar esa información del documento JSON y guardarlo a la base de datos.

El documento JSON es este. Lo doy a conocer en la totalidad de su estructura con el objetivo de poder dimensionar el error que tengo en caso tal:

```
{
  "paciente": {
    "id": 1234,
    "nombre": "Pablo Andrés Agudelo Marenco",
    "sesion": {
      "id": 3,
      "juego": [
        {
          "nombre": "bonzo",
          "nivel": [
            {
              "id": 1234,
              "nombre": "caida libre",
              "segmento": [
                {
                  "id": 12345,
                  "nombre": "Hombro",
                  "movimiento": [
                    {
                      "id": 1234,
                      "nombre": "Flexion",
                      "metricas": [
                        {
                          "min": 12,
                          "max": 34,
                          "media": 23,
                          "moda": 20
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "___léeme___": "El array 'iteraciones' contiene las vitorias o derrotas con el tiempo en segundos de cada iteración",
              "iteraciones": [
                {
                  "victoria": true,
                  "tiempo": 120
                },
                {
                  "victoria": false,
                  "tiempo": 232
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

En mi vista basada en clase del detalle de un objeto `RehabilitationSession` es en donde leo el documento JSON y comparo los identificadores tanto del objeto en la base de datos como el del `JSON` (`["paciente"]["sesion"]["id"]`) y si coinciden procedo con el guardado de datos.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
class RehabilitationSessionDetail(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = RehabilitationSession
    template_name = 'rehabilitationsession_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'sessiondetail'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context=super(RehabilitationSessionDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user

        with open('ProcessedMetricsFinal.json') as data_file:
            session_data=json.loads(data_file.read())
            context['session_data'] = session_data

            #Capturar el ID de la sesión del JSON
            session_id_json = session_data["paciente"]["sesion"]["id"]

            #Capturar el ID de la sesión de la base de datos
            session_id_db=int(self.kwargs.get('pk'))

            #Comparar esos dos ID, si son iguales:
            if session_id_db==session_id_json:
                # Guardando datos a la base de datos
                for record in session_data:
                    RehabilitationSession.objects.filter(id=session_id_db).update(
                        minimum=record['min'],
                        maximum=record['max'],
                        median=record['media'],
                        mode=record['moda'])
            else:
                context=super(RehabilitationSessionDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            return context
```

Entonces cuando voy a mi url de detalle, que es la que llama a esta vista,  cuando se cumple la condición de comparar los id's tanto del documento JSON y el objeto en la base de datos, obtengo el siguiente error:

```
File "/home/bgarcial/workspace/neurorehabilitation_project/medical_encounter_information/views.py", line 187, in get_context_data
    minimum=record['min'],
TypeError: string indices must be integers
[17/Nov/2016 02:07:17] "GET /sesiones-de-rehabilitacion/3 HTTP/1.1" 500 122694
```

No se si tal vez como estoy indagando en mi vista por las claves `min`, `max`, `media`, `moda` las cuales están en un nivel de identación mayor ... ¿deba recorrerlo con varios índices en mi ciclo `for`?

Cualquier orientación es altamente apreciada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error es que estas iterando sobre un string, el error dice que los indices no pueden ser 'strings' si no 'enteros'... Recuerda que al iterar sobre un diccionario no puedes hacerlo como una lista normal (sabiendo que los JSON son diccionarios para python), de modo que si tu los recorres como lo estas haciendo en esta linea:

```
...
for record in session_data: # estas accediendo a cada llave de el JSON principal
...
```

lo correcto seria iterar sobre el diccionario asi: `for key, value in session_data.items():` pero para no dañar mucho tu código, si sabes que lo que tienes en tu variable `record` son strings, deberias iterar asi:

```
...
for key in session_data:
    record = session_data[key]['sesion']['juego'][0]['nivel'][0]['segmento'][0]['movimiento'][0]['metricas'][0]
    RehabilitationSession.objects.filter(id=session_id_db).update(
        minimum=record['min'],
        maximum=record['max'],
        median=record['media'],
        mode=record['moda']
    )
...
```

La razón por la que uso los indices 0 es porque tu JSON contiene arrays y dentro de los arrays están los diccionarios...

Espero con esta respuesta haberte orientado y puedes mejorar el código de muchas formas, no tiene que ser asi, lo hago asi solo por fines demostrativos... cualquier duda, comenta

Comment: muchas gracias, tu duda me ayudo a guardar los datos. Me queda la inquietud de cuando en el JSON, en la clave de metricas, hayan mas subdocumentos, es decir inicialmente el campo donde desee guardarlas debe ser `ManyToMany`, pero ¿como leer cuando en el array de metricas haya mas de un subdocumento? Es decir leer de manera dinámica cuantos documentos metricas vengan en ese array, asi sea uno, dos, tres, n...

Comment: mmm si solo necesitas saber el tamaño, como el diccionario en su llave 'metrica' es una lista de python, puedes usar la funcion de `len()`, seria como `len(diccionario['llave']['key']['...']['metricas'])`, ahora, si debes guardarlo siempre, puedes recorrerlo normal en un ciclo for como cualquiera otra lista, que si tiene tamaño uno, lo recorrerra una vez, y si tiene mas, las veces que sea necesario, a fin de que no estes preguntando por el tamaño